# Determinant formed by cofactors

Tags: determinant, indeterminate-forms

We are given $$\Delta_0 = \begin{vmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{vmatrix} \neq 0.$$

And let $\Delta_1$ denote the determinant formed by the cofactors of elements of $\Delta_0$, and $\Delta_2$ denote the determinant formed by cofactors of $\Delta_1$. Then we have to find value of $\Delta_n$ in terms of $\Delta_0$.

I tried a lot, but did not get any start.

Answer (score 3):

For this, we first need to know the concept of *Reciprocal Determinant*. It is defined as: When in a given determinant, each element is replaced by it’s cofactor, then the determinant so formed is called reciprocal determinant of the given determinant. If the original determinant is $D$, then the reciprocal determinant is given by $D'$.

> **Theorem**: If $D$ is a determinant of order $n$, and $D'$ be its reciprocal determinant then $D' =D^{n-1}$.
> **Proof**: Let
> $$ D=
>   \det{\begin{vmatrix}
>     a_1 & b_1 & \cdots & n_1\\
>     a_2 & b_2& \cdots & n_2\\
>     \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>     a_n & b_n & \cdots & n_n\\\
> \end{vmatrix}}
> $$ and
> $$ D'=
>   \det{\begin{vmatrix}
>     A_1 & B_1 & \cdots & N_1\\
>     A_2 & B_2& \cdots & N_2\\
>     \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>     A_n & B_n & \cdots & N_n\\\
> \end{vmatrix}}
> $$ where uppercase letters denote the cofactors of the lowercase letters. Also, we know that $a_iA_j+b_iB_j+\ldots+n_iN_j=D$ where $i=j$ and $a_iA_j+b_iB_j+\ldots+n_iN_j=0$ when $i\neq j$. Thus on multiplying $D$ and $D'$, we have
> $$ DD'=
>     \det{\begin{vmatrix}
>     D & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
>     0 & D & \cdots & 0\\
>     \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>     0 & 0 & \cdots & D\\\
> \end{vmatrix}} =D^{n}.
> $$ Thus $D'=D^{n-1}$.

Hope you can then take it from here on successive iterations of this theorem.

Comment: According to me through this theorm the answer should be delta(0)$^(n-1)^n$

Comment: According to me through this theorm the answer should be delta(0)^(n-1)^n but the anwser is delta(0)^2^n

Comment: @J.Doe Here $n$ is the order of the determinant which is $3$. Hence we have $D_2= D'^{2}=D^{4}$ and similarly we can find $D_n$. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

|D1|=|Cd0| =|D0|^n-1                           { properties=|adj.[a]|=|a|^n-1} here order is 3

|D2|=|Cd1|=|D0|^(n-1)^2

|D3|=|Cd2|=|D0|^(n-1)^3

|Dn|=|Cd(n-1)=|D0|^(3-1)^n

|Dn|=|Cd(n-1)=|D0|^2n

|Dn|=|D0|^2n