# Finding the determinant of cofactor matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let

\begin{align}
\Delta &= 
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\ 
x_4 & x_5 & x_6 \\ 
x_7 & x_8 & x_9
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align}

and let $C_i$ represent the cofactor of $x_i$.

Find

\begin{align} 
\begin{vmatrix}
C_1 & C_2 & C_3 \\ 
C_4 & C_5 & C_6 \\ 
C_7 & C_8 & C_9
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align}
in terms of $\Delta$.

Generalize that if $\Delta$ represents the determinant of a $n\times n$ matrix, then the determinant of the cofactor matrix is $\Delta^{n-1}$.

---

Looking at the generalization, I was tempted to multiply both determinants.

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\ 
x_4 & x_5 & x_6 \\ 
x_7 & x_8 & x_9
\end{vmatrix}
\times 
\begin{vmatrix}
C_1 & C_2 & C_3 \\ 
C_4 & C_5 & C_6 \\ 
C_7 & C_8 & C_9
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1C_1+x_2C_2+x_3C_3 & x_1C_4+x_2C_5+x_3C_6 & x_1C_7+x_2C_8+x_3C_9 \\ 
x_4C_1+x_5C_2+x_6C_3 & x_4C_4+x_5C_5+x_6C_6 & x_4C_7+x_5C_8+x_6C_9 \\ 
x_7C_1+x_8C_2+x_9C_3 & x_7C_4+x_8C_5+x_9C_6 & x_7C_7+x_8C_8+x_9C_9
\end{vmatrix}
$$

$$
\implies
\Delta
\times 
\begin{vmatrix}
C_1 & C_2 & C_3 \\ 
C_4 & C_5 & C_6 \\ 
C_7 & C_8 & C_9
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
\Delta & x_1C_4+x_2C_5+x_3C_6 & x_1C_7+x_2C_8+x_3C_9 \\ 
x_4C_1+x_5C_2+x_6C_3 & \Delta & x_4C_7+x_5C_8+x_6C_9 \\ 
x_7C_1+x_8C_2+x_9C_3 & x_7C_4+x_8C_5+x_9C_6 & \Delta 
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Can someone help me figure out the next step? (This huge determinant must be equal to $\Delta^3$.)

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045108/determinant-formed-by-cofactors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

> first of all prove for yourself that $$x_1C_4+x_2C_5+x_3C_6=0$$.

Symmetrically it is easy to see that all the elements other than the ones in diagnal($i=j$) are zero.Thus we have \begin{vmatrix}
\Delta & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & \Delta & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & \Delta \\ 
\notag
\end{vmatrix} which comes out to be ${\Delta}^3$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** For every square matrix $A$ of size $n \geq 2$, denote by $C(A)$ the matrix of its cofactor. Then $A$ is invertible iff $C(A)$ is invertible, and you have the relation
$$A \times (C(A))^T = \det(A) I_n$$

Comment: I'm a mere beginner in linear algebra. I would like an explanation for why that relation holds true.

Comment: I guess you should find this relation in every linear algebra course. See for example : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Inverse_of_a_matrix

Answer (score 0):

The matrix which you have posted is also known as the ‘Cofactor Matrix’. The transpose of this cofactor matrix is more commonly used, and is known as the adjoint or adjugate of the matrix, denoted by $\operatorname{adj}(A)$.

It is a well known (and easily proven) property for an square matrix of order $n$ that
$$ A\,\operatorname{adj}(A) = |A|\,I_n, $$
where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of order $n$ and $|A|$ represents the determinant of the matrix $A$, $\Delta$. From here, it follows that $|A|\,|\operatorname{adj}(A)|= |A|^n$ and hence, $|\operatorname{adj}(A)| = |A|^{n-1}$.

We also know that the determinant of a matrix is the same as that of its transpose (since we are only interchanging the rows and columns). Hence the determinant of the cofactor matrix should also be $|A|^{n-1}$.

Comment: Try proving the property for a 2x2 or 3x3 matrix if you are feeling confused.